# How to add string to the end of each array element using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am to finish the function below. I am to loop through the arr paramteter using a for loop and add the string "Duck" to the end of each element `(i.e. arr[0] = "yellow"; should become "yellowDuck".`

Here is what I am given to start with:

```
function addDucks(arr, ind) {

  //WRITE YOUR FOR-LOOP HERE
  //For your iterator, declare it with the let keyword, and name it "i"


  //DO NOT TOUCH THIS
  return [arr, ind]
}
```

Here is the code I am trying:

```
function addDucks(arr, ind) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    return arr[i] + 'Duck';
  }
  return [arr, ind]
}
```

Comment: What is the issue that you are encountering when running the code you wrote.  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @bmartin I expect it to pass these tests: `should return an array
the first element of the returned array should be the passed-in array with "Duck" added to every element
the second element of the returned array should be 3 when passed [1, 2, 3], 3`

Comment: As the answer below states - you are returning the concatenation of only the first element, instead of modifying the array's values.

Comment: Tell your teacher the right answer is: "You don't use a [for loop](https://decembersoft.com/posts/understanding-javascript-closures-in-for-loops/), that's what [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) was created for" but if you insist on mutating there is also forEach

Comment: @HMR I know. I think it's just to make sure we know about for loops as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was close, you were just not changing the reference in the array to be the string with `Duck` added. Modified the `return arr[i] + 'Duck'` to `arr[i] += 'Duck'` which is the same as `arr[i] = arr[i] + 'Duck'`

```js
function addDucks(arr, ind) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i] += 'Duck';
  }
  return arr;
}
let ducks = addDucks(['green','purple'], 2);
console.log(ducks);
```